# bytebuddy apply advice to interface methods - specifically spring data jpa

Tags: byte-buddy

I am trying to LOG all methods that are invoked in my Springboot application using byte-buddy based java agent.

I am able to log all layers except Spring data JPA repositories, which are actually interfaces. Below is agent initialization:

```
        new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .type(ElementMatchers.hasSuperType(nameContains("com.soka.tracker.repository").and(ElementMatchers.isInterface())))
            .transform(new AgentBuilder.Transformer.ForAdvice()
                    .include(TestAgent.class.getClassLoader())
                    .advice(ElementMatchers.any(), "com.testaware.MyAdvice"))
            .installOn(instrumentation);
```

any hints or workaround that I can use to log when my repository methods are invoked. Below is a sample repository in question:

```
package com.soka.tracker.repository;
.....
@Repository
public interface GeocodeRepository extends JpaRepository<Geocodes, Integer> {
  Optional<Geocodes> findByaddress(String currAddress);
}
```

Modified agent:

```
    new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .ignore(new AgentBuilder.RawMatcher.ForElementMatchers(any(), isBootstrapClassLoader().or(isExtensionClassLoader())))
            .ignore(new AgentBuilder.RawMatcher.ForElementMatchers(nameStartsWith("net.bytebuddy.")
                    .and(not(ElementMatchers.nameStartsWith(NamingStrategy.SuffixingRandom.BYTE_BUDDY_RENAME_PACKAGE + ".")))
                    .or(nameStartsWith("sun.reflect."))))
            .type(ElementMatchers.nameContains("soka"))
            .transform(new AgentBuilder.Transformer.ForAdvice()
                    .include(TestAgent.class.getClassLoader())
                    .advice(any(), "com.testaware.MyAdvice"))
            //.with(AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemOut())
            .with(AgentBuilder.TypeStrategy.Default.REDEFINE)
            .installOn(instrumentation);
```

I see my advice around controller and service layers - JPA repository layer is not getting logged.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Byte Buddy ignores synthetic types in its agent. I assume that Spring's repository classes are marked as such and therefore not processed.

You can set a custom `ignore` matcher by using the `AgentBuilder` DSL. By default, the following ignore matcher is set to ignore system classes and Byte Buddy's own types:

```
new RawMatcher.Disjunction(
    new RawMatcher.ForElementMatchers(any(), isBootstrapClassLoader().or(isExtensionClassLoader())),
    new RawMatcher.ForElementMatchers(nameStartsWith("net.bytebuddy.")
      .and(not(ElementMatchers.nameStartsWith(NamingStrategy.SuffixingRandom.BYTE_BUDDY_RENAME_PACKAGE + ".")))
      .or(nameStartsWith("sun.reflect."))
      .<TypeDescription>or(isSynthetic())))
```

You would probably need to remove the last condition.

Comment: Hi, Thank you @rafael. so are you suggesting that it wont be able to capture / advice such proxies with bytebuddy & use ignore functionality as above to ignore them completely?

Comment: Yes, but you would need to include such classes in your ignore configuration. If you add an `ignore` step, you replace the existing ignore matcher.

Comment: thanks @Rafael - modified agent to include `ignore` - pls see edited main question. Spring Data JPA layer is not logged. I appreciate your help - let me know if something is still missing - else I guess the proxies generated by Spring / Hibernate arent covered.

Comment: Does it not show up in the logs as ignored and discovered either? Maybe Spring Boot defines these classes as anonymous classes. Can you get hold of an implementation of such an interface and check (a) if it is marked as synthetic and (b) what class loader is loading the class? You simply need the instance and get the info from `instance.getClass()`.

Comment: for the actual interface itself - those show up in logs since Spring is creating the instances and injecting - `SERVING REQUEST -- static com.soka.tracker.repository.GeocodeRepository() : []` is one such example - though no advices is logged further during actual method invocation. `SimpleJPARepository` is 1 target implementation of the methods defined inside above mentioned interface. If I try to enforce advice around SimpleJPARepository, the app fails to start completely - `IllegalStateException: No MethodInvocation found: Check that an AOP invocation is in progress, and that the  is upfront

Comment: full exception is `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No MethodInvocation found: Check that an AOP invocation is in progress, and that the CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor is upfront in the interceptor chain.`

Answer (score 0):

for anybody visiting this question / problem - I was able to go around the actual problem with logging actual queries invoked during execution - Bytebuddy is awesome and very powerful - for ex- in my case I am simply `advice`'ing on my db connection pool classes and gathering all required telemetry -

`.or(ElementMatchers.nameContains("com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection"))`